# [__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:]: fromDate cannot be nil

Tags: ios, iphone, nscalendar

I am getting this error .How to solve it.Please suggest me.
**Crash Report**
[__NSCFCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options:]: fromDate cannot be nil
I mean really, what do you think that operation is supposed to mean with a nil fromDate?
An exception has been avoided for now.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply silently do whatever random thing results from the nil.
Here is the backtrace where this occurred this time (some frames may be missing due to compiler optimizations):
**My code**

```
NSString *str_babyedays=aMileBusiness.str_DAte;
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"EN"];
    NSDate *titemdate = [df dateFromString: str_babyedays];



    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                                fromDate:titemdate
                                                  toDate:currentDate options:0];

    NSInteger months = [components month];
    NSInteger day= [components day];
```

Comment: Show a log of str, so we can see it's format. That format must match the one you use in setDateFormat for your formatter.

Comment: NSDate *titemdate = [df dateFromString: str_babyedays];

Comment: Put in this log, NSLog(@"%@",str_babyedays), and report what it shows.

Comment: the titemdate is -->(null) and strbabydays date is--->11-01-2014 13:53 PM

Comment: Your date formatter's dateFormat must match the input string in order for it to convert the string to a date. This: 11-01-2014 13:53 PM does not match this: dd-MM-yyyy. You need to add the time components as well to the format string.

Answer (score 4):

Your `titemdate` is nil because your `NSDateFormatter` was unable to parse a date from `str_babyedays`. Straight from the Apple documentation for `NSDateFormatter`:

> If `dateFromString:` can not parse the string, returns `nil`.

You can look at any of these questions to determine why it's `nil`.

[NSDateFormatter dateFromString conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069228/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-conversion)

[NSDateFormatter dateFromString Always Returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300032/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-always-returns-nil)

[dateFromString always returns null with dateformatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638416/datefromstring-always-returns-null-with-dateformatter)

Comment: Thanks for giving answer.NSDate *dateFromString = [df dateFromString:str_babyedays]; Its not working for me.wha's the reason.